# Can the mother determine the tribe of the son if her father had no sons and she was married to a gentile

Tags: genealogy, book-of-chronicles

There are several passages that clearly say that the tribe of the son is the tribe of the father.

I saw only below the passage that seems to say that the mother's tribe was passed onto her son.

Tanakh does not share any details but I am asking if

1. Did the mother's tribe pass on to Attai.
2. Did the Egyptian Slave convert to Judaism and there by assimilated into the tribe of Judah and there by Attai's tribe continues in the tribe of Judah.

**1 Chronicles 2:34** And Sheshan had no sons but daughters, and Sheshan had an Egyptian slave named Jarha. 35 And Sheshan gave his daughter to Jarha his slave for a wife, and she bore him Attai. 36 And Attai begot Nathan, and Nathan begot Zabad.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the commentaries and none of them say that Attai was a member of the tribe of Judah. The law is clear that descent goes by the father even if one has a Jewish mother. See [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.24.9?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Leviticus.24.10&ven2=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann,_1929-1934&vhe2=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann,_1929-1934&lang2=en)

> A Baraitha states that ויצא means, he came out of the judicial court of Moses where he had been pronounced to be in the wrong in the following matter: although his father was an Egyptian he had gone to pitch his tent in the camp of the tribe of Dan to whom his mother belonged (cf. v. 11). They (the men of Dan) said to him, “What have you to do here" (lit., what is your character that gives you the right to come here?). He replied. “I am one of the children of the tribe of Dan”. Thereupon they said to him, “Scripture states: (Numbers 2:2) “Every man [of the children of Israel shall encamp] by his own standard, that bears the signs of their father’s house”! He thereupon went in to the judicial court of Moses to have the matter decided and came forth (יצא) declared to be in the wrong. He then stood up and blasphemed (Sifra, Emor, Section 14 1; Leviticus Rabbah 32 3).

Comment: But the below passage seems to indicate that he was part of the genealogy. 1 Chronicles 2:36 And Attai begot Nathan, and Nathan begot Zabad.

Comment: He was, but that would not give him a tribal status. He was considered to be descended from David on his mother's side, as the commentaries identify him with the Yishmael of Jeremiah 41 who is referred to as from "the seed of the royalty", but that does not mean he was an actual member of the tribe of Judah.